# One-to-many foreign key constraints in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was wondering if there is a good way to model one to many relationships with postgres 9.6 (i.e. have an array of foreign keys). I know its doable via junction tables but I'm wondering if there's a simpler solution (like creating a custom trigger/constraint in postgres). Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to have a single row in a table be able to reference multiple rows in foreign tables

Comment: Add FK to the other table...

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statements for the tables in question and a description on how exactly you want to define those foreign keys. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to reference many tables from a single row. Something like this will do it.

```
CREATE TABLE a(
    columnA integer references B(columnName) ,
    columnB integer references C(columnName) ,
    columnC integer references D(columnName) ,
etc.......
);
```

In my opinion something like this is asking for a headache.

Answer (score -1):

Having a variety of foreign keys is not a problem. This is part of the entity-relationship model and its normal forms.

N-N relationship entities should only be used in many-to-many cases.

If your table has many foreign keys, the logical model of your data must be verified, it may be poorly modeled.